# I am trying to fetch recent chat for my laravel website. but query returning wrong output

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

i am trying to create chat for my website in laravel. i am selecting the recent chats for the user where user can see the list of users with whom he chat.
Here are my query:

```php
$data=[];
$chatusers = Chat::latest()->get(['reciver_id']);
$chatusers = collect($chatusers)->unique()->values()->all(); 

foreach ($chatusers as $user) {
    if ($user['reciver_id']>=5000) {
        $message=Chat::where('reciver_id',$user['reciver_id'])
            ->latest()
            ->first();

        array_push($data,$message);
    } else {
        $message=Chat::where('sender_id',$user['reciver_id'])
            ->orWhere('reciver_id',$user['reciver_id'])
            ->latest()
            ->first();

        array_push($data,$message);
    }
}
```

Here i am attaching screens of DB tables:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKEKs.jpg

Here is screen for chat-list:-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VAmH.jpg

i am not managing relationship.

please help with this.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please post (the relevant bits of) your models and also what error your output is + what your expected output is in text form in your question please? :) You say you are not managing relationships, does this mean you don't have a relationship between user and chat?

Comment: i am referring query result as output. if you see https://imgur.com/Jw81yeH you will get that there are 2 result of same chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $login_user_id = 1; // use auth user_id
   $chat = Chat::where(function($q) use($login_user_id){
        $q->where('sender_id',$login_user_id)>orWhere('receiver_id',$login_user_id);
        $q->where('receiver_id',$login_user_id)->orWhere('sender_id',$login_user_id);
    })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();
        $other_user_id = [];
        $message = [];
   foreach ($chat as $key => $value) {
      if(in_array($value->sender_id, $other_user_id) || in_array($value->receiver_id, $other_user_id)){
                continue;
            }
            if($value->sender_id != $login_user_id){
                $other_user_id[] = $value->sender_id;
            }else{
                $other_user_id[] = $value->receiver_id;
            }

            $message[] = $value;

        }
        print_r($message);
```

You have to add table to manage unread messages.

Comment: we also have groups whose id is greater than 5000 when i tried to merge with my code these conditions are being fail.

Comment: $group_id='array of groups_id';if ($value['reciver_id'] >5000 && in_array($value['reciver_id'], $group_id)) {
                $other_user_id[] = $value['reciver_id'];
            }

Comment: you have to add condition into code. I don't understand why you are using above conditions. you have already take both if and else part into result. by default all value goes into response array.

Comment: yes i have changed condition in $chat = Chat::where(function($q) use($login_user_id){
  $q->where('sender_id',$login_user_id)->orWhere('reciver_id',$login_user_id)
  ->where('reciver_id',$login_user_id)->orWhere('sender_id',$login_user_id)
  ->orWhereIn('reciver_id', $group_id);
  })->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();

Comment: please try this one: Chat::where(function($q) use($login_user_id){
        $q->where('sender_id',$login_user_id)>orWhere('receiver_id',$login_user_id);
        $q->where('receiver_id',$login_user_id)->orWhere('sender_id',$login_user_id);
    })->whereIn('reciver_id', $group_id)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get()->toArray();